# How to go about listening on different ports on socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

So I have an online game that I have created with socketio that currently listens on port 3000 and just does everything on there. Now what?

I would like to make it so that someone can create a "room" and then people join the room with a code, and I'm thinking have multiple ports be different rooms, so there can be a game running on port 2020 and another on 3000.

So my question is, how do I convert my current setup to this room system. I'm assuming I'd need a central app.js that would create the rooms? Or is it done another way.

Also I am open to ideas, this is new to me so I don't know the conventional way of doing the room system, maybe there is another way completely? My game uses socket.io though.

Answer (score 1):

There is already room/name-spacing functionality baked into [socket.io](https://socket.io/).

You can find the documentation in [Rooms and Namespaces](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/).

#### Basic example:

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.join('some room')
  io.to('some room').emit('some event')
})
```

.. will emit `'some-event'` to all the sockets that `join()` a room with name `'some-room'`.

When you get around to implementing the above, the [`emit()` cheatsheet](https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/) will help *immensely*.

---

There is absolutely no need to start eating up a port for each room nor create your own room-join logic.

Comment: oh sweet, never knew that existed. so i basically only should have ONE app.js running right? thanks.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying. For the record, I'm running 8 forked app.js files using [cluster](https://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/) but that's for scalability purposes, not for implementing rooms/namespaces. That's a whole different story though

Comment: hey, don't know if you could see this but I have been trying to get my mind around how I would implement this to my game, and just can't. is there a way I could contact you and then share screen or get some live help?

Comment: My schedule is as full as it gets. Send me an email here nik.kyriakides(a-t)gmail.com and I'll try to reply when I get some time on my hands. I would highly recommend you ask around in the [socket.io Slack channel](https://slackin-socketio.now.sh/) instead of waiting for me to get back to you